# Help with "Duplicate id in List"

Tags: apex, trigger, class, list

I've recently started at a new company with a completely different instance. Recently I've noticed a growing amount of errors looking like

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: CaptureCard_Trigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.ListException: Duplicate id in list: a0z1Q000008MO73QAG Class.CCHelper_Handler.findRelationship: line 34, column 1 Trigger.CaptureCard_Trigger: line 11, column 1

This is preventing the creation of around 10% of records and causing some major havoc... Be it that I have little experience with extremely long APEX Classes I was hoping for a little guidance?

**APEX TRIGGER:**

```
trigger CaptureCard_Trigger on CaptureCard__c (before insert, after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if( Trigger.isBefore ){
        if( Trigger.isInsert ){
          CCHelper_Handler.convertCardCE( Trigger.New );
        }
    } 
    if( Trigger.isAfter ){
        if( Trigger.isInsert ){
            RollupSumCards_Handler.count( Trigger.New );
          CCHelper_Handler.findRelationship( Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.NewMap );
          CCHelper_Handler.findContract( Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.NewMap );
        }
        if( Trigger.isUpdate ){
          CCHelper_Handler.findRelationship( Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.NewMap );
          CCHelper_Handler.findContract( Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.NewMap );
        }
        if( Trigger.isDelete ){
          RollupSumCards_Handler.count( Trigger.Old );
        }
    }
}
```

**APEX CLASS:**

```
public class CCHelper_Handler {

    public static void findRelationship( Map<Id,CaptureCard__c> OldMap, Map<Id,CaptureCard__c> NewMap ){

        List<CaptureCard__c> Cards = new List<CaptureCard__c>();
        Map<Id,Id> Card_RX = new Map<Id,Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> Card_CE = new Map<Id,Id>();

        for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Contract__c,Relationship__c,Entity__c,Pharmacy__c,Entity_CaptureCard__c,Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c
                                       FROM CaptureCard__c WHERE Id IN :NewMap.keySet() ]){
            if(EachCard.RecordTypeId == '0121Q000001I4yRQAS' && EachCard.Relationship__c == NULL){
                Cards.add(eachCard);
                Card_RX.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Pharmacy__c);
              Card_CE.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c);
            }
        }

        List<Relationship__c> foundRels = [SELECT Id,Account__c,Related_Account__c FROM Relationship__c WHERE (Related_Account__c IN :Card_RX.values() AND Account__c IN :Card_CE.values()) ORDER BY LastModifiedDate desc];

        List<CaptureCard__c> updateCards = new List<CaptureCard__c>();

        if(foundRels.size()>0){
            for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : Cards ){
                for(Relationship__c eachRel : foundRels){
                    if( Card_RX.get(EachCard.Id) == eachRel.Related_Account__c && Card_CE.get(EachCard.Id) == eachRel.Account__c){
                        EachCard.Relationship__c = eachRel.Id;
                        updateCards.add(EachCard);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(updateCards.size()>0){
          update updateCards;
        }
    }

    public static void findContract( Map<Id,CaptureCard__c> OldMap, Map<Id,CaptureCard__c> NewMap ){

        List<CaptureCard__c> Cards = new List<CaptureCard__c>();
        Map<Id,Id> Card_RX = new Map<Id,Id>();
        Map<Id,Id> Card_CE = new Map<Id,Id>();

        for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Contract__c,Relationship__c,Entity__c,Pharmacy__c,Entity_CaptureCard__c,Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c
                                       FROM CaptureCard__c WHERE Id IN :NewMap.keySet() ]){
            if(EachCard.RecordTypeId == '0121Q000001I4yRQAS' && EachCard.Contract__c == NULL){
                Cards.add(eachCard);
                Card_RX.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Pharmacy__c);
              Card_CE.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c);
            }
        }

        List<Contract> foundContracts = [SELECT Id,AccountId,Entity_Account__c
                                         FROM Contract WHERE (AccountId IN :Card_RX.values() AND Entity_Account__c IN :Card_CE.values()) ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC];

        List<CaptureCard__c> updateCards = new List<CaptureCard__c>();

        if(foundContracts.size()>0){
            for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : Cards ){
                for(Contract eachContr : foundContracts){
                    if( Card_RX.get(EachCard.Id) == eachContr.AccountId && Card_CE.get(EachCard.Id) == eachContr.Entity_Account__c){
                        EachCard.Contract__c = eachContr.Id;
                        updateCards.add(EachCard);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(updateCards.size()>0){
          update updateCards;
        }
    }

    public static void convertCardCE( List<CaptureCard__c> NewRecords ){

        Map<Id,Id> CE_CC = new Map<Id,Id>();

        for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : [SELECT Id,Entity__c FROM CaptureCard__c WHERE RecordTypeId = '0121Q000001I4yMQAS' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate ASC]){
            CE_CC.put(EachCard.Entity__c,EachCard.Id);
        }

        for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : NewRecords ){
            if(EachCard.RecordTypeId == '0121Q000001I4yRQAS' && EachCard.Entity__c != NULL){
                EachCard.Entity_CaptureCard__c = CE_CC.get(EachCard.Entity__c);
              EachCard.Entity__c = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be extremely helpful... Thank you all.

Comment: Hi Joshua,
Looking at the CCHelper_Handler class in the lines just before the `update updateCards;` statement there is the double-for-loop over `Cards` and ´foundRels`. This may add the same `EachCard` record multiple times to the `updateCards` list if the `foundRels` list contains more than one entry. This leads to the error during the `update...` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that a DML `update` is being performed on some `List<sObject>`, and the relevant list contains the same object multiple times.

Scanning through `updateRelationships()`, the proximate cause is this line:

```
      update updateCards;
```

which is performing an `update` on a `List<CaptureCard__c>`. The better, and more typical, pattern is to accumulate these updates in a `Map<Id, CaptureCard__c>` keyed on the object's `Id`, which ensures that you only add each object to the collection once.

The root cause, though, is the logical structure of this code.

This is not ideal, but it's only part of the problem here:

```
    for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Contract__c,Relationship__c,Entity__c,Pharmacy__c,Entity_CaptureCard__c,Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c
                                   FROM CaptureCard__c WHERE Id IN :NewMap.keySet() ]){
        if(EachCard.RecordTypeId == '0121Q000001I4yRQAS' && EachCard.Relationship__c == NULL){
            Cards.add(eachCard);
            Card_RX.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Pharmacy__c);
          Card_CE.put(EachCard.Id,EachCard.Entity_CaptureCard__r.Entity__c);
```

Those filters should be part of the query (on `RecordType.DeveloperName`, not a hard-coded Id!), and I'd rather assign the query to `Cards` and iterate over that collection here and below, rather than building it iteratively.

`Card_CE` and `Card_RX` should probably be multi-maps, i.e., `Map<Id, List<CaptureCard__c>>`, to cope with the possibility of multiple Cards per related record in this transaction. See below for more.

Here's the real issue, though:

```
    if(foundContracts.size()>0){
        for(CaptureCard__c EachCard : Cards ){
            for(Contract eachContr : foundContracts){
                if( Card_RX.get(EachCard.Id) == eachContr.AccountId && Card_CE.get(EachCard.Id) == eachContr.Entity_Account__c){
```

This is an O(N*M) search; expensive and wasteful. Instead, for each Contract, use its values `AccountId` and `Entity_Account__c` to index into your existing Maps, which is O(1) (constant time). Then (assuming these Maps became multi-maps, as recommended above), you would iterate over the Lists of Cards keyed under those related records.

```
                    EachCard.Contract__c = eachContr.Id;
                    updateCards.add(EachCard);
```

Now I think what's happening here is that you've got multiple Contracts matching some of your Cards, so they get added to `updateCards` multiple times. *That's* ultimately why the DML fails.

All that said, there's a lot I/we don't know about this code and what it's meant to do, and I may have dramatically misunderstood the business intent. I think I've identified the core technical issue here, but you likely have even more work to do to better define what the behavior is expected to look like when you match multiple Contracts to the same Cards and vice versa.